# How do I find the max in each group when the calculation is done with count(*)?

Tags: sql, db2

I've been trying to find the max of each member of a group using advices from other posts, but seems this is a different problem as the counter is based on a count(*) not on an specific column.

My table has several columns; the ones I need: date and branch. Each record of the table represents a transaction in that branch. I would need to know for each date which is the branch with more transactions and how many they were done.

I started with:

```
Select date, branch, count(*) as total
from table
group by date, branch
```

I attempted a max(total) but this would just give me a row instead of one per group.

I tried joining with itself, something like this, but it doesn´t work because maxim is not recognized in the having clause:

```
Select date, branch, count(*) as maxim
(Select date, branch, count(*) as total
from table
group by date, branch) a
having maxim=max(total)
group by date, branch
```

Any idea?, thanks!

Comment: Group by should do it. Careful on your example, you use count(*) not max(total) for the maxim, I guess this is just a typo in SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t1.date, t2.branch, t1.max_total
from (
  select date, max(total) as max_total
  from (
    select date, branch, count(*) as total 
    from mytable 
    group by date, branch) as x
  group by date    
) as t1    
join (
  select date, branch, count(*) as total 
  from mytable 
  group by date, branch
) as t2 on t1.date = t2.date and t1.max_total = t2.total
```

The idea is to use the query you started with twice as a derived table:

- The first time you use it in order to get the maximum number per `date`
- The second time you use it in order to extract the `branch` value having a `total` count equal to the maximum number. There may be more than one branches in case of ties.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6354b0/4)

If DB2 supports window functions you may use the following, which, if applicable, is more efficient:

```
select date, branch, total
from (
  select date, branch, count(*) as total,
         rank() over (partition by date order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from mytable
  group by date, branch) as t
where t.rn = 1
```

Comment: @NatBI Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE 
    ([Date] date,Branch varchar(10),trans int)

INSERT INTO @table
    (
        [Date],
        Branch,
        trans
    )
    VALUES
    ('2015-01-01','b1',1),('2015-01-01','b1',2),('2015-01-01','b1',3),
    ('2015-01-02','b1',4),('2015-01-02','b1',5),('2015-01-02','b1',6),
    ('2015-01-01','b2',1),('2015-01-01','b2',2),('2015-01-01','b2',3)

Select 
    [Date], Branch, COUNT(trans) AS total
FROM 
    @table
GROUP By 
    [Date], Branch
    ORDER BY [Date]
```